# Regular expression in java to match XML

Tags: java, regex

I'm locked in a regex problem. I must put "<*strong>" and "<*/strong>" tags at the sides of some String, along a larger String. For example, if I have:

```
"This is a test, and test word appears two times"
```

And the String selected is "test", it will remains:

```
"This is a <_strong>test<_/strong>, and <_strong>test<_/strong> word appears two times"
```

At first, I think in use regex functions combined with "ReplacedAll". The problem comes when there are <_strong> tags in the larger String, some like that:

```
"This is a test, and <_strong>test word<_/strong> appears two times"
```

It will remain something like that:

```
"This is a <_strong>test<_/strong>, and <_strong><_strong>test<_/strong> word<_/strong> appears two times"
```

The idea is for find a regular expression that modify the string "test" only if there isn't between <_strong> tags. But I'm not able for find it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @chrylis http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182189/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant

Comment: @sp00m Fair enough. I suppose it just hasn't taken me long to get to the point where I sympathize with the author...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use double negative lookaheads for this:

```
test(?!(?:(?!<_strong>).)*<_/strong>)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/aN6oN5)

This makes sure that the `test` is not followed by a `<_/strong>` (unless there's an opening `<_strong>` in between).

`(?! ... )` is a negative lookahead. It prevents a match if the previous expression is followed by the expression inside the negative lookahead.

E.g.

`a(?!b)` will match all `a` not followed by `b`.

`(?!(?:(?!<_strong>).)*<_/strong>)` has two negative lookaheads. First we could say that there is `(?!.*<_/strong>)`. When you have `test(?!.*<_/strong>)`, this will match all `test` unless they have a `<_/strong>` after them. Now, this wouldn't work for the second sentence because even the first `test` has a `<_/strong>` after it.

The trick is that a `test` is considered to be within `<_strong>` tags only if there isn't an opening `<_strong>` tag between `test` and `<_/strong>`. That is where the `.*` turned into `(?:(?!<_strong>).)*`

You can play around in the regex101 demo site I linked in my answer earlier.

Comment: Thank you, that code works perfectly. However I'm below in knowledge that a noob. Can you explain me how it works exactly?

Comment: @user2814276 I added some more explanation to my answer, if it helps